# How to append values from a JSON to an array?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm trying to get values from a JSON and append them to `titleArray`.

```
func updateUI() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            // network call to the API
            self.fetchTipsJson(completion: { (res) in
                switch res {
                case .success(let tips):
                     self.titleArray.append(tips.responseList!.values[title]) // Cannot subscript a value of type '[Value]' with an index of type 'String?'
                    print(self.titleArray)

                case .failure(let err):
                    print("Failed to fetch tips:", err)
                }

            })
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // Update the UI Label here

            }
        }
    }
```

I get an error but I don't think this is how it's supposed to be done.

The JSON:

```
{
    "$type": "DTOMapper.DTOResponseList`1[[Telemed.Dto.DTOTip, Telemed.Dto]], DTOMapper",
    "ResponseList": {
        "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Telemed.Dto.DTOTip, Telemed.Dto]], mscorlib",
        "$values": [
            {
                "$type": "Telemed.Dto.DTOTip, Telemed.Dto",
                "Title": "NO TE JUNTES CON LUQUITAS",
                "Text": "Porque si tenes un amigo lucas y otro amigo lucas, tenés dos lucas. Pero no te sirven para pagar nada",
                "GroupName": "TGC.Tips1",
                "ConfigurationPath": "TelemedGlobalConfig>Tips>Tips[0]"
            },
            {
                "$type": "Telemed.Dto.DTOTip, Telemed.Dto",
                "Title": "no te emborraches en las fiestas",
                "Text": "Terminarás pateando globos",
                "GroupName": "TGC.Tips2",
                "ConfigurationPath": "TelemedGlobalConfig>Tips>Tips[1]"
            }
        ]
    },
    "StatusCode": 200,
    "ErrorId": 0
}
```

Am I accessing the `$values` correctly? If it helps, `titleArray` will be used with an UILabel.

Edit for `updateLabels()`:

```
func updateLabels() {
        self.myTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: true) { (t) in
            self.titleLabel.text = self.titleArray[self.counter] as? String
            self.textLabel.text = self.textArray[self.counter] as? String
            self.counter += 1
            if self.counter == self.titleArray.count && self.counter == self.textArray.count{
                t.invalidate()
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit for callback:

```
do {
            let tips = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data!)
            self.titleArray = tips.responseList!.values.map { $0.title }
            self.textArray = tips.responseList!.values.map { $0.text }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.updateLabels()
            }
            completion(.success(tips))
        } catch let jsonError {
            completion(.failure(jsonError))
        }
```

Edit for `viewDidLoad()`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        fetchTipsJson { (res) in
            switch res {
            case .success:
                return
            case .failure(let err):
                print("Failed to fetch tips:", err)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`values` is an array not a dictionary , you need to map it to the `title` string , so try

```
let str = """

{
"$type": "DTOMapper.DTOResponseList`1[[Telemed.Dto.DTOTip, Telemed.Dto]], DTOMapper",
"ResponseList": {
"$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Telemed.Dto.DTOTip, Telemed.Dto]], mscorlib",
"$values": [
{
"$type": "Telemed.Dto.DTOTip, Telemed.Dto",
"Title": "NO TE JUNTES CON LUQUITAS",
"Text": "Porque si tenes un amigo lucas y otro amigo lucas, tenés dos lucas. Pero no te sirven para pagar nada",
"GroupName": "TGC.Tips1",
"ConfigurationPath": "TelemedGlobalConfig>Tips>Tips[0]"
},
{
"$type": "Telemed.Dto.DTOTip, Telemed.Dto",
"Title": "no te emborraches en las fiestas",
"Text": "Terminarás pateando globos",
"GroupName": "TGC.Tips2",
"ConfigurationPath": "TelemedGlobalConfig>Tips>Tips[1]"
}
]
},
"StatusCode": 200,
"ErrorId": 0
}
"""



do {
      let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: Data(str.utf8))
      let arr = res.responseList.values.map { $0.title }
      print(arr)
   }
   catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

---

```
// MARK: - Empty
struct Root: Codable {
    let type: String
    let responseList: ResponseList
    let statusCode, errorID: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case type = "$type"
        case responseList = "ResponseList"
        case statusCode = "StatusCode"
        case errorID = "ErrorId"
    }
}

// MARK: - ResponseList
struct ResponseList: Codable {
    let type: String
    let values: [Value]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case type = "$type"
        case values = "$values"
    }
}

// MARK: - Value
struct Value: Codable {
    let type, title, text, groupName: String
    let configurationPath: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case type = "$type"
        case title = "Title"
        case text = "Text"
        case groupName = "GroupName"
        case configurationPath = "ConfigurationPath"
    }
}
```

---

**Edit:**

```
var counter = 0

var myTimer:Timer!

self.myTimer =    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: true) { (t) in
    self.lbl.text = self.titleArr[self.counter]
    counter += 1
    if self.counter == self.titleArr.count {
        t.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The values.map worked perfectly! If it's no bother, how would you use the `titleArray` with an UILabel? `updateUI()` is supposed to cycle the UILabel every few seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it. I get `Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range` on line `self.titleLabel.text = self.titleArray[self.counter] as? String`. I suppose that edit goes on `viewDidLoad()` right? Except the `var counter`.

Comment: wrap the above edit inside a function and call it after you fill the titleArr inside the callBack

Comment: Did it, but nothings changing. The UILabel doesn't even show the data from the JSON

Comment: wrap function call inside `DispatchQueue.main.async{}` also hold a reference to the timer see edit

Comment: timer triggers ? added a print to verify ?

Comment: Wait, it worked! It's almost done, now the thing is, the label doesn't start with data, so it just says "Label", the timer starts and after the time passes, then it changes to the data provided by the JSON. Oh, and it never comes back to the first title/text, when it gets to the last it just stays there.

Answer (score 0):

First thing `tips.responseList!.values` is an `Array` not `Dictionary`. So you can't do like

```
self.titleArray.append(tips.responseList!.values[title])
```

You can do it by iterating all element inside the array.

```
self.titleArray.append(contentsOf:tips.responseList!.values.compactMap { $0.title })
```

Please ignore the syntax error because it is a just idea.